# "The" extended familiy

Tags: grammar, articles

Why we have to use "the" before "extended family" in this sentence.

> He studied the roll of **the** extended family in caring for older
>   people.

I mean what is the grammatical reason?

Comment: We don't *have* to include the article, as evidenced by about 912 results in Google Books for [*the role of extended family in {whatever}.*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventhough **the** is used when referring to a specific noun, it can also be used to refer to a group in general.

> The British
>   The Americans
>   the family
>   the children
>   the extended family

and especially when you want to emphasize that particular noun and the noun is  classifying noun.

For example, in a report on naval operations, it might be said

> **The** aircraft carrier has many advantages over **the** destroyer in projecting power.

although equivalent to

> **An** aircraft carrier has many advantages over **a** destroyer in projecting power.

the second sentence lacks a certain type of emphasis as in

> **the** greatest vs **a** greatest

"***The*** *extended family*" can be though of in this way, the same as

> Feed ***the*** Children